# Front panel audio jacks not working after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm running Kubuntu on an ASUS HM81-PLUS motherboard. It has a RealTek ACL887 audio chip. I have never had a problem with the audio until I upgraded to 20.04 yesterday. Now the front panel jacks (microphone & earphones) do not work. Specifically the Plasma audio mixer app does not detect when a microphone or earphones are plugged in and so they do not work with any apps. Alsamixer shows the front microphone as being not muted with max gain and the earphones muted. If I unmute the earphones, they work but it does not survive a reboot. If I plug the microphone into the back panel jack, it is detected and works. (I have run a live Kubuntu 18.04 from a memory stick and everything is working OK.)

I've spent many hours searching the web and nothing I've see works. Among the things I've tried are:

1. using hdajackretask to overide the settings.
2. "arecord -l" shows an alternative sound card, so I insert "load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,2" into /etc/pulse/default.pa . A microphone appeared in the Plasma mixer but it did not produce an audio signal in Zoom or Skype.
3. I tried using versions 3 and 3.2 (instead on 3.6) of libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils

I guess I could use the rear jacks but I don't like leaving the microphone plugged in all of the time and everything worked before 20.04!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Some output:

dmesg | grep snd

```
[    3.232493] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.267957] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC887-VD: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    3.267959] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.267960] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.267961] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.267962] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    dig-out=0x11/0x0
[    3.267963] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    3.267964] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    3.267966] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    3.267967] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x1a
[    7.751169] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: pin nid 6 not registered
[    7.766586] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: pin nid 6 not registered
```

arecord -l

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec

```
Codec: Intel Haswell HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
```

I ran

```
curl https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/raw/master/src/utils/pa-info?inline=false | bash | nc termbin.com 9999
```

The output was saved at https://termbin.com/3h0z (but I don't know for how long).

Update:

It occurred to me that I could run the "curl https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio ..." command from a live Kubuntu 18.04 distro and look at the differences in the output. There were quite a few differences. Most of them looked insignificant to me. The exceptions are listed below.

alsactl output: Differences between:

- control.13: value.0, value.1
- control.14: value.0, value.1
- control.20: value

Kubuntu20.04:

```
    control.13 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Playback Volume'
        value.0 31
        value.1 31
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 31'
            dbmin -3450
            dbmax 1200
            dbvalue.0 1200
            dbvalue.1 1200
        }
    }
```

Kubuntu18.04:

```
    control.13 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Playback Volume'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 31'
            dbmin -3450
            dbmax 1200
            dbvalue.0 -3450
            dbvalue.1 -3450
        }
    }
```

Kubuntu20.04:

```
    control.14 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Playback Switch'
        value.0 true
        value.1 true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
```

Kubuntu18.04:

```
    control.14 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Playback Switch'
        value.0 false
        value.1 false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
```

Kubuntu20.04:

```
    control.20 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Input Source'
        value 'Rear Mic'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 'Front Mic'
            item.1 'Rear Mic'
            item.2 Line
        }
    }
```

Kubuntu18.04:

```
    control.20 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Input Source'
        value 'Front Mic'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 'Front Mic'
            item.1 'Rear Mic'
            item.2 Line
        }
    }
```

pactl list: Differences between "Source #1"

Kubuntu20.04:
[nothing]

Kubuntu18.04:

```
Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 10387 /  16% / -48.00 dB,   front-right: 10387 /  16% / -48.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 37"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,10438576,00100302"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, not available)
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, not available)
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, not available)
    Active Port: analog-input-front-mic
    Formats:
        pcm
```

amixer output: differences in "Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0: Item0"

Kubuntu20.04:

```
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Front Mic' 'Rear Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Rear Mic'
```

Kubuntu18.04:

```
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Front Mic' 'Rear Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Front Mic'
```

Another Update

I am beginning to suspect my problem is to do with the kernel. The command "sudo hdajacksensetest -c 1" gives

```
Pin 0x14 (Green Line Out, Rear side): present = Yes
Pin 0x18 (Pink Mic, Rear side): present = No
Pin 0x19 (Pink Mic, Front side): present = No
Pin 0x1a (Blue Line In, Rear side): present = No
Pin 0x1b (Green Headphone, Front side): present = No
```

so that the jack detection process is not detecting the front panel mic. I ran the same command with the mic in the back panel and it works OK.